Google Drive Java API fileMetadata modifiedTime not working
With the Google Drive Java API, modifying the modifiedTime doesn't work. The update call always sets the current time instead of the one I specify.
 File fileMetadata = new File();

            // Set the new modified time
            
            DateTime newModifiedTime = new DateTime(lastModified);      
            
            fileMetadata.setModifiedTime(newModifiedTime);
           // fileMetadata.setDescription(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

            File file = ....
            
            
            service.files().update(file.getId(), fileMetadata)
                    .setFields("id, name, modifiedTime")
                    .execute();


Try this modification to the update call:
service.files().update(file.getId(), fileMetadata)
      .setFields("files(id, name, modifiedTime)")
      .execute();


Hi, thanks. Your modification doen't work. I think the problem is from the process. A have a first process to upload a file and a second process to update the modifiedTime. With a little Thread.sleep between these 2 calls, it Works ! This is not a good solution but the problem is identified. Prehaps a problem relative to the google infrastructure ?
